# How can I optimize this query, takes more than a min to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query which take more than a minute to execute, how can I optimize it. Its slow because of **order by o.id desc**, if I remove it query executes it few ms.

```
select o.*, per.email, p.name
from order o 
inner join product p 
on o.product_id=p.id 
inner join person per 
on o.person_id=per.id 
order by o.id desc 
limit 100;
```

Following is the result of explain

```
1   SIMPLE  p   index   PRIMARY FK2EFC6C1E5DE2FC    8   NULL    6886    Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  o   ref FK67E9050121C383DB,FK67E90501FC44A17C   FK67E90501FC44A17C  8   dev.p.id    58  
1   SIMPLE  per eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   dev.o.person_id 1   Using index
```

All the tables are InnoDB and joins are on Primary and Foreign keys. Other than that indexes are on **email** column in **Person** and **status** column in **Order**

Number of records in each table

Person : 1,300,000
Product: 7,000
Order  : 70,000

Comment: Please post your table structure as well

Comment: did you add index on each attribute you are using for relations? (person_id, id, product_id,..)?

Comment: Please post all the indexes that exist on these tables

Comment: all the joins are on primary and foreign key and as table types are InnoDB all joined columns should be indexed by default, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The planner, most probably, is not using the `limit` hint to eliminate rows from order table before the join. So the server has to do the join for all rows and then return just a few.

Try this:

```
select o.* from
(select * order order by id desc limit 100) o
inner join product p 
on o.product_id=p.id 
inner join person per 
on o.person_id=per.id 
order by o.id desc limit 100;
```

EDIT: This will work only if there is a constraint guaranteeing that corresponding rows are present in Product and Person tables.

Comment: Even though this would probably speed up the process, it doesn't give accurate result. What if one of these 100 rows couldn't be joined? Then you'd get 99 rows instead of 100.

Comment: You are right. Didn't think about it. But it also depends on how the tables are setup. If there is a foreign key constraint on those columns then it won't be a problem.

Comment: If you asume that all these tables are connected correctly, this join wouldn't be needed at all since only o.* is fetched.

Comment: actually its not just o.* but per.email and p.name ... sorry missed that

Comment: Try this query, but with the `limit 100` at the bottom and only `order by id desc` at the 2nd row (none at the bottom).

Comment: @RobinCastlin - If you order a sub-query and then join it, the order in the sub-query becomes incedental.  SQL is compiled into a plan and the plan may not join the data in the order of the query.  This all means the data can come out in a completely different order and need re-ordering again.

Comment: @Priyank - Actually the op says the joins are FKs on to PKs. By definition the records exist, and each order matches to exactly one product and exactly one person. Add `per.email and p.name` to the select and this may be a good answer.

Comment: @Dems: And yet nothing was said with regard to whether the FKs are nullable or not. (Although I admit, in this particular case the absent product and/or the absent person would hardly make any sense.)

Comment: @AndriyM - Doh, you're right. What has been state only means : 1 order record to 0 or 1 person records, and 0 or 1 product records. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i understand your question, in this case first of all, save your query in .sql file.
 you can use sql server utility  called "Database Engine Tuning Advisor" in Tools menu of the Sql Server Management studio.

first open sql server and go to tools and select option "Database Engine Tuning Advisor".
then select the file you stored previously.
now tick mark your database which you are using and table which is used in query and then 
click on Start Analysis in main menu. 
it show you possible index and statestics to create
now to apply this recommandation to your query, go to action manu and select "Apply Recommandation" that will create indexes and statestics on  on your table and reduce the execution time of query.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of this variabled and restart MySQL server [read_rnd_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_rnd_buffer_size)
setting the variable to a large value can improve ORDER BY performance by a lot.

Also you can refer http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/24/what-exactly-is-read_rnd_buffer_size/