# Most efficient way to LIMIT results in a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

I have a fairly simple one-to-many type join in a MySQL query. In this case, I'd like to LIMIT my results by the left table.

For example, let's say I have an `accounts` table and a `comments` table, and I'd like to pull 100 rows from `accounts` and all the associated `comments` rows for each.

Thy only way I can think to do this is with a sub-select in in the FROM clause instead of simply selecting FROM `accounts`. Here is my current idea:

```
SELECT a.*, c.* FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM accounts LIMIT 100) a
    LEFT JOIN `comments` c on c.account_id = a.id
    ORDER BY a.id
```

However, whenever I need to do a sub-select of some sort, my intermediate level SQL knowledge feels like it's doing something wrong.

Is there a more efficient, or faster, way to do this, or is this pretty good?

**By the way...**

This might be the absolute simplest way to do this, which I'm okay with as an answer. I'm simply trying to figure out if there IS another way to do this that could potentially compete with the above statement in terms of speed.

Comment: It certainly works...but I don't know if "well" because I don't know what to / if i even can, compare to. I'm just trying to figure out my options, and I can run tests.

Comment: Well, looks ok to me. I don't have another query at the moment :)

Comment: Thanks :) That's what I'm wondering - if it's really the 'only' simple way to do this...if there is nothing else to really consider a competitor for speed

Comment: For your scenario, yes, it looks like the easiest offering.  As you get into more complex / restrictive queries, the concept could also be just as good for "PreQualifying" records in the same fashion.

Comment: @DRapp Thanks, you mean as I add more joins, etc? For example, when I also wanna get all their 'blog posts' or something?

Comment: @johnnietheblack, not exactly, but say you wanted all accounts of a certain type, or created within a certain range.... that can be applied to the inner "pre-query" like you have would be able to apply additional criteria before joining to the rest to get other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks perfect to me.

Just wondering if it is ok with you to receive less or more than 100 rows from the above query.
Because if for a particular row of `accounts` table there are no rows in `comments` table then you would get less than 100 rows. Similarly if there are multiple matching rows in `comments` table for a row in `accounts` table then you may get more than 100 rows.

See: [How can I optimize this query, takes more than a min to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924643/how-can-i-optimize-this-query-takes-more-than-a-min-to-execute/9924939#9924939)

Comment: The number of returned rows doesn't matter really...its the number of returned accounts that I really care about in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No, The query is fine, just the way it is. You might want to filter the fields instead of `a.*` and `c.*` though.

Comment: Totally agree with not using `a.*` and `c.*`...in fact the real one goes into detail on which cols to select...just got lazy in the question :)